# Google bigquery - Error message 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_parquet' whereas pyarrow and fastparquet are installed

Tags: dataframe, google-bigquery, pyarrow, fastparquet

I'm trying to use the Google bigquery function `load_table_from_dataframe` but I get an error message stating that `DataFrame` object has no attribute `to_parquet`.
I have installed both `pyarrow` and `fastparquet` but still getting the same error message

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'Test_Name':['Charlotte','Alexis'],'Test_Age':[31,12]})
table_id = 'TEST_DF.TEST_TABLE'
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df_test, table_id,job_config=job_config)
job.result()
```

I'm using Python 3.6.3 and pyarrow version 0.14.0
Any idea on what is causing the issue?

Comment: It might help to share which versions of the pandas, pyarrow, etc that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with:

```
$ pip install --upgrade pandas
```